# Randomizing part of array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random, integer

Lets say I have an array of integers. I found out that I can randomize the order of the elements simply by doing:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
array = array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

But lets say I want to keep the first and the last elements in their original place. Can I do it using the same approach (using OrderBy()) or do I need to re-think my situation?

Comment: There might be a cleaner solution, but just save the first and last elements and then reinsert them in the randomized list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a single expression, but maybe a `List<int>` could help:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(array[0]);
var partialArray = array.Skip(1).Take(array.Length - 2);
list.AddRange(partialArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
list.Add(array[array.Length -1 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use the same approach, but you have to take care of the first and the last value. Just an example for your input `array`:

```
var list = array.Skip(1).Take(array.Length - 2).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
list.Insert(0, array.First());
list.Add(array.Last());
array = list.ToArray();
```

Dmitry's example is basically the same, but gives you the option to keep more elements.

Comment: Dang, too slow, I had written almost the exact same thing character by character!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

```
        int[] ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        ints = ints.Select((x, index) => new { Value = x, Index = index })
               .OrderBy(tuple => (tuple.Index >= start && tuple.Index <= stop) ? random.Next(start, stop) : tuple.Index)
               .Select(tuple => tuple.Value)
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a standard shuffle algorithm modified to use a range, for example (using [the Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)):

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array, Random rng, int start, int end)
{
    for (int n = end+1; n > start+1;)
    {
        int k = rng.Next(start, n);
        --n;
        T temp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Random rng = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    var array = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToArray();
    Shuffle(array, rng, 3, 9);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach which doesn't involve using List....

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        //array = array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        int lastIndexToChange = array.Length - 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < lastIndexToChange; i++)
        {
            var tempStore = array[i];
            int newPosition = rnd.Next(1, lastIndexToChange);

            array[i] = array[newPosition];
            array[newPosition] = tempStore;
        }
```